# Constantly getting Crashloopbackoff error in Kubernetes PODS generally in MongoDB pods

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, rancher

I'm constantly getting this Crashloopbackoff error when a pod tries to get up. Problem generally occurs in Mongodb pods. However, when I delete the problematic pod it creates itself successfully, you can find necessary kubectl command outputs below. Thanks in advance.
kubectl describe pod game-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-2
command output:

```
Name:         game-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-2
Namespace:    xxxxxxxxxx-database
Priority:     0
Node:         xxxxxxxxxx-sandbox-worker02/aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
Start Time:   Fri, 24 Jul 2020 04:19:10 +0000
Labels:       app=mongodb-replicaset
              controller-revision-hash=game-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-5cdf769c8
              release=game-mongodb-rs
              statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=game-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-2
Annotations:  checksum/config: 305b3f0fc0746c5b648686d14caa985a818d739ea09e6a4c399b31f502c87d9f
              cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/32
              cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/32
Status:       Running
IP:           aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
IPs:
  IP:           aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/game-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset
Init Containers:
  copy-config:
    Container ID:  docker://60f1d94ccff87526f488346628577177c460927601b311b2d096e0f9c2b680e0
    Image:         ranchercharts/busybox:1.29.3
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://busybox@sha256:8ccbac733d19c0dd4d70b4f0c1e12245b5fa3ad24758a11035ee505c629c0796
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      sh
    Args:
      -c
      set -e
      set -x
      
      cp /configdb-readonly/mongod.conf /data/configdb/mongod.conf
      
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Fri, 24 Jul 2020 04:19:40 +0000
      Finished:     Fri, 24 Jul 2020 04:19:40 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /configdb-readonly from config (rw)
      /data/configdb from configdir (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-42mq5 (ro)
      /work-dir from workdir (rw)
  install:
    Container ID:  docker://1b54cf209cb756a2c8dd5bf2f7f9541833e854262e25cdb6fe7eb42c12cbcd17
    Image:         ranchercharts/unguiculus-mongodb-install:0.7
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://ranchercharts/unguiculus-mongodb-install@sha256:a3a0154bf476b5a46864a09934457eeea98c4e7f240c8e71044fce91dc4dbb8b
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Args:
      --work-dir=/work-dir
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Fri, 24 Jul 2020 04:19:42 +0000
      Finished:     Fri, 24 Jul 2020 04:19:42 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-42mq5 (ro)
      /work-dir from workdir (rw)
  bootstrap:
    Container ID:  docker://2a667087d1591a91d42c2acdaa2c331bf83c5bdddb1eb74bcbef1d32cb4bdb27
    Image:         ranchercharts/mongo:3.6
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://ranchercharts/mongo@sha256:1459c57632dbe16aa3f58ab989b8862e7fe2659b2b8730c65d30c31d27d0066d
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /work-dir/peer-finder
    Args:
      -on-start=/init/on-start.sh
      -service=game-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Fri, 24 Jul 2020 04:19:44 +0000
      Finished:     Fri, 24 Jul 2020 04:19:51 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      POD_NAMESPACE:  xxxxxxxxxx-database (v1:metadata.namespace)
      REPLICA_SET:    rs0
      TIMEOUT:        900
    Mounts:
      /data/configdb from configdir (rw)
      /data/db from datadir (rw)
      /init from init (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-42mq5 (ro)
      /work-dir from workdir (rw)
Containers:
  mongodb-replicaset:
    Container ID:  docker://f67fbdb1e2d155d87ec9d9c55f575654202d674ea10a0238d0e6738bbe1d077f
    Image:         ranchercharts/mongo:3.6
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://ranchercharts/mongo@sha256:1459c57632dbe16aa3f58ab989b8862e7fe2659b2b8730c65d30c31d27d0066d
    Port:          27017/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Command:
      mongod
    Args:
      --config=/data/configdb/mongod.conf
      --dbpath=/data/db
      --replSet=rs0
      --port=27017
      --bind_ip=0.0.0.0
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    100
      Started:      Wed, 29 Jul 2020 03:07:31 +0000
      Finished:     Wed, 29 Jul 2020 03:07:31 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  1083
    Liveness:       exec [mongo --eval db.adminCommand('ping')] delay=30s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      exec [mongo --eval db.adminCommand('ping')] delay=5s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /data/configdb from configdir (rw)
      /data/db from datadir (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-42mq5 (ro)
      /work-dir from workdir (rw)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  datadir:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  datadir-game-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-2
    ReadOnly:   false
  config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      game-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-mongodb
    Optional:  false
  init:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      game-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-init
    Optional:  false
  workdir:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  configdir:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  default-token-42mq5:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-42mq5
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                       From                              Message
  ----     ------   ----                      ----                              -------
  Normal   Pulled   33m (x1077 over 4d22h)    kubelet, xxxxxxxxxx-sandbox-worker02  Container image "ranchercharts/mongo:3.6" already present on machine
  Warning  BackOff  3m7s (x26140 over 3d19h)  kubelet, xxxxxxxxxx-sandbox-worker02  Back-off restarting failed container
```

kubectl logs game-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-2 command output:

```
2020-07-29T03:07:31.381+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=game-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-2
2020-07-29T03:07:31.381+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.14
2020-07-29T03:07:31.381+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: cbef87692475857c7ee6e764c8f5104b39c342a1
2020-07-29T03:07:31.381+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2020-07-29T03:07:31.381+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2020-07-29T03:07:31.381+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-07-29T03:07:31.381+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-07-29T03:07:31.381+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2020-07-29T03:07:31.381+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-07-29T03:07:31.381+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-07-29T03:07:31.381+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/data/configdb/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "0.0.0.0", port: 27017 }, replication: { replSet: "rs0" }, storage: { dbPath: "/data/db" } }
2020-07-29T03:07:31.381+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: DBPathInUse: Unable to create/open the lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock (Read-only file system). Ensure the user executing mongod is the owner of the lock file and has the appropriate permissions. Also make sure that another mongod instance is not already running on the /data/db directory, terminating
2020-07-29T03:07:31.381+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2020-07-29T03:07:31.381+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

> kubectl describe pvc datadir-game-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-2

```
Name:          datadir-game-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-2
Namespace:     xxxxxxxxxx-database
StorageClass:  longhorn
Status:        Bound
Volume:        pvc-74f88284-94ca-4a8a-98a8-afc8276aaa9e
Labels:        app=mongodb-replicaset
               release=game-mongodb-rs
Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
               volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: driver.longhorn.io
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      2Gi
Access Modes:  RWO
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    game-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-2
Events:        <none>
```

> kubectl get pvc

```
NAME                                                       STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
account-mongodb                                            Bound    pvc-3efd0ea0-0a78-44f9-8f14-c18863884ee0   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       64d
admin-mysql                                                Bound    pvc-5df04bd0-52fd-4e20-add7-d35f00e7d13a   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       64d
cms-mongodb                                                Bound    pvc-8668df66-24f7-4c2c-8344-34bed512db25   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       64d
currency-influxdb-data-currency-influxdb-0                 Bound    pvc-bfec5613-b3bb-40ad-a381-c19c52b7a0a0   8Gi        RWO            longhorn       35d
currency-influxdb2                                         Bound    pvc-3127b79d-7842-4ae5-acff-f55038db6079   8Gi        RWO            longhorn       35d
data-admin-mariadb-cluster-master-0                        Bound    pvc-2c43c9b4-0fd7-4f57-a4bb-41bab38d6535   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       12d
data-admin-mariadb-cluster-slave-0                         Bound    pvc-5b88e0ee-ebba-4036-bee4-66e7732d9a47   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       12d
data-admin-mariadb-cluster-slave-1                         Bound    pvc-2579bc42-c4b0-4271-8cd5-3138678b5be7   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       12d
data-admin-mariadb-master-0                                Bound    pvc-2fd8ac2b-1ec4-4567-9f5c-4bcdbbd77b73   1Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
data-admin-mariadb-rs-master-0                             Bound    pvc-6c8d323b-ed01-4f08-b8de-7e1583dc568a   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
data-admin-mariadb-rs-slave-0                              Bound    pvc-37de9d2f-9ae1-4bf9-8ade-9e7a53a63dbd   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
data-admin-mariadb-rs-slave-1                              Bound    pvc-ae899713-6ec6-4a50-addd-26c5a2d6c52f   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
data-admin-mariadb-slave-0                                 Bound    pvc-8b0213dd-c893-499d-a849-0a4aa9c2e7c6   1Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
data-admin-mariadb-slave-1                                 Bound    pvc-682a3d47-9c5e-450f-a1c2-4bfeeb88ea18   1Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
data-user-mariadb-cluster-master-0                         Bound    pvc-2df955ab-873b-4802-b3f8-92699b0ed70f   8Gi        RWO            longhorn       12d
data-user-mariadb-cluster-slave-0                          Bound    pvc-fc0fd146-41bf-4fce-8241-31471a3ace24   8Gi        RWO            longhorn       12d
data-user-mariadb-cluster-slave-1                          Bound    pvc-bbae306b-c8eb-4436-89da-b278001e208d   8Gi        RWO            longhorn       12d
data-user-mariadb-master-0                                 Bound    pvc-37a368e5-4cce-473c-984d-01cfa4d2823a   8Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
data-user-mariadb-slave-0                                  Bound    pvc-2f6d963f-35eb-4f32-a9e5-723a2353dbf8   8Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
data-user-mariadb-slave-1                                  Bound    pvc-af3a5572-563e-49a4-8cd5-9cd4306b3b9d   8Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
datadir-account-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-0            Bound    pvc-6cf2aaaf-a024-413d-9f01-8190bf92a255   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
datadir-account-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-1            Bound    pvc-04e57232-6438-4e1c-9c84-534c8b5c3d1e   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
datadir-account-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-2            Bound    pvc-9d5e431e-6461-494c-a41b-bcb14e5b0196   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
datadir-cms-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-0                Bound    pvc-5859c00f-5d36-4d0f-88c2-871ba4687015   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
datadir-cms-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-1                Bound    pvc-ce289ed3-e1bd-413c-845e-efa24a2d7325   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
datadir-cms-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-2                Bound    pvc-8b2b040d-ee21-4fc8-afb8-733b553d1a47   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
datadir-game-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-0               Bound    pvc-f9e45fe2-f0d5-4653-bdec-c51160224c13   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       19d
datadir-game-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-1               Bound    pvc-bb918533-5aa6-450e-93de-9e9952213fc4   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       19d
datadir-game-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-2               Bound    pvc-74f88284-94ca-4a8a-98a8-afc8276aaa9e   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       19d
datadir-game-provider-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-0      Bound    pvc-3ba540d5-a399-4e35-9d09-16e1e09b9d31   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
datadir-game-provider-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-1      Bound    pvc-24a0c6e6-dde4-4b01-b6f3-ec287f92961f   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
datadir-game-provider-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-2      Bound    pvc-c0645909-4cb2-4730-9143-655711e3adaf   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
datadir-logger-mongodb-mongodb-replicaset-0                Bound    pvc-cc6aa705-2e84-4a2a-9c14-53525d5b0299   4Gi        RWO            longhorn       55d
datadir-logger-mongodb-mongodb-replicaset-1                Bound    pvc-eab44c76-0f8d-4059-afa7-0694399fe094   4Gi        RWO            longhorn       55d
datadir-logger-mongodb-mongodb-replicaset-2                Bound    pvc-dd92f594-250a-4aa4-a2aa-2286196b63a7   4Gi        RWO            longhorn       55d
datadir-payment-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-0            Bound    pvc-c8f0d4d2-396a-49fe-8a39-2f23f771c17b   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
datadir-payment-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-1            Bound    pvc-d48518fa-fab8-40aa-91cf-ec782c125458   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
datadir-payment-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-2            Bound    pvc-f0860cf0-2ba9-4ea3-8b79-ea5ac6dd051a   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
datadir-payment-provider-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-0   Bound    pvc-87a15e18-969c-43eb-bac5-3a9e515db0bc   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
datadir-payment-provider-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-1   Bound    pvc-74a0b6f5-929e-4894-901c-8792b424823e   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
datadir-payment-provider-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-2   Bound    pvc-53e6b2e0-86be-4e53-a7c7-b2d315623651   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
datadir-report-mongodb-mongodb-replicaset-0                Bound    pvc-32ced54a-b9c0-4d08-97e7-023c3ad3ed9d   4Gi        RWO            longhorn       35d
datadir-report-mongodb-mongodb-replicaset-1                Bound    pvc-33f04787-c208-4c61-8701-dc289abdc59b   4Gi        RWO            longhorn       35d
datadir-report-mongodb-mongodb-replicaset-2                Bound    pvc-77603bd5-f2d6-4578-9c42-159da8899767   4Gi        RWO            longhorn       35d
datadir-transaction-mongodb-mongodb-replicaset-0           Bound    pvc-dfba2184-c312-4c09-be36-8c56b2e23a43   4Gi        RWO            longhorn       62d
datadir-transaction-mongodb-mongodb-replicaset-1           Bound    pvc-eca84f3f-0a32-4146-9cdf-d38ce23f13c5   4Gi        RWO            longhorn       62d
datadir-transaction-mongodb-mongodb-replicaset-2           Bound    pvc-1cddf3be-e784-4e31-bb91-a99c784e0a75   4Gi        RWO            longhorn       62d
game-mongodb                                               Bound    pvc-e843ce38-8f5c-4b65-bfe3-0722ff7c8c15   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       33d
game-provider-mongodb                                      Bound    pvc-b45e4bf4-591b-4a32-8653-a7dc702135fa   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       62d
mysql-data-admin-mysql-rs-pxc-0                            Bound    pvc-894cb5a9-9efe-4929-b4bf-f74e9f222c09   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
mysql-data-admin-percona-rs-pxc-0                          Bound    pvc-d12126b5-74ef-45da-8619-fdfbdfa10624   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
mysql-data-xxxxxxxxxx-admin-rs-pxc-0                           Bound    pvc-ec3aa8a3-7c7f-44d0-b8ad-69ec33c05d7e   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
mysql-data-xxxxxxxxxx-admin-rs-pxc-1                           Bound    pvc-75000123-9665-4691-8b6d-73998e15b232   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
mysql-data-xxxxxxxxxx-admin-rs-pxc-2                           Bound    pvc-72526ddc-ad4d-4b2b-88c0-86c3031dd87a   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       13d
payment-mongodb                                            Bound    pvc-cdca0a65-3a8b-40d3-80d7-89019eef8a04   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       62d
payment-provider-mongodb                                   Bound    pvc-a8b89ed6-34a1-4932-bad5-ed5608407497   2Gi        RWO            longhorn       62d
```

> kubectl describe pv pvc-9d5e431e-6461-494c-a41b-bcb14e5b0196

```
Name:            pvc-9d5e431e-6461-494c-a41b-bcb14e5b0196
Labels:          <none>
Annotations:     pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by: driver.longhorn.io
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection external-attacher/driver-longhorn-io]
StorageClass:    longhorn
Status:          Bound
Claim:           xxxxxxxxxx-database/datadir-account-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-2
Reclaim Policy:  Delete
Access Modes:    RWO
VolumeMode:      Filesystem
Capacity:        2Gi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:         
Source:
    Type:              CSI (a Container Storage Interface (CSI) volume source)
    Driver:            driver.longhorn.io
    VolumeHandle:      pvc-9d5e431e-6461-494c-a41b-bcb14e5b0196
    ReadOnly:          false
    VolumeAttributes:      baseImage=
                           fromBackup=
                           numberOfReplicas=2
                           staleReplicaTimeout=30
                           storage.kubernetes.io/csiProvisionerIdentity=1594625809090-8081-driver.longhorn.io
Events:                <none>
```

Comment: `kubectl describe pod <pod>` and `kubectl logs <pod>` please

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and pay especial attention to the section that says not to use images for error messages. Be sure you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63142792/edit) when you provide the logs that Serge requested. Good luck

Comment: @Serge I've edited my question with the command outputs that you've requested, thanks for rapid response.

Comment: @mdaniel I'm quite new to SO, thanks for the welcome, I'll read to how to ask section and will try to obey the rules, thanks for the reminder :)

Comment: Please `kubectl describe pvc datadir-game-mongodb-rs-mongodb-replicaset-2` and `kubectl get pvc` doesnt hurt either. And if a PV is bound to the PVC, please describe that too

Comment: @Serge I've provided the outputs that you've asked. And yeah, Persistentvolume bound to that specific pvc.

Comment: can you `kubectl describe pv pvc-9d5e431e-6461-494c-a41b-bcb14e5b0196` please

Comment: @Serge I've edited the question with the output of command that you've asked too. Thank you so much for all the help mate.

Comment: Did you install this via this chart https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mongodb-replicaset? Did you set `persistentVolume.enabled` to `true` when you ran `helm install`?

Comment: @Serge actually I've just joined the team and couldn't get much information how the previous person installed this. But I think I can manage to learn your question's answer in a few hours. Should I reinstall it via above mentioned chart in case I can't get the needed answers?

Comment: TBH it looks like the `helm install` would have been configured just fine given your PVCs and PVs are all `RWO`.  Might want to check your version of the Helm Chart and redeploy to latest version if it is not up to date.

Comment: @Serge thank you very much for all the help again mate, I'll try to do as you said. On the other hand could this problem related to mongodb user rights? Since this problem goes away once I delete the problematic replica and problem only occurs only when an active replica starts to have problem and need to be recreated automaticly. Some google research lead me to
```
chown -R mognodb:mognodb /data/db
``` 
command might fix the problem.

Comment: Yep it looks like a permissions problem but the helm installation should sort this out for you